# Rust deserialize Vec of u32 to Vec of enum

Tags: json, rust, struct, deserialization, serde

I'm looking for a good way to deserialize a `Vec` of `u32` to a `Vec` of `enum`.
So basically I'm receiving a json object like this:

```json
{
  "Account": "r...",
  "Flags": 20,
  ...
}
```

The `struct` I'm trying to deserialize it into looks something like this:

```rust
#[skip_serializing_none]
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all(serialize = "PascalCase", deserialize = "snake_case"))]
pub struct Foo<'a> {
  account: &'a str,
  flags: Option<Vec<FooFlag>>
}
```

`FooFlag` looks something like this:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize, Display, AsRefStr)]
pub enum FooFlag {
  Example1 = 5,
  Example2 = 15,
  ...
}
```

Now after I've received the json I want to derive the `Vec<FooFlag>` from that `u32` `Flags` value. So for this example it should be `vec![FooFlag::Example1, FooFlag::Example2]` (5 + 15 = 20). How I decide that these are the two enums doesn't matter for now.
I would like to have a deserialization function that I could use for multiple structs like `Foo`.
I know there are crates like `serde_repr` for C-like enums but I didn't manage to put it together in a generic way.

---

So far I've written a `mod`:

```rust
mod flag_conversion {
    use alloc::vec::Vec;
    use serde::{Deserializer, Serializer, Deserialize};

    fn serialize<'a, T, S>(flags: &'a Option<Vec<T>>, s: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        T: Into<u32>,
        S: Serializer,
    {
        s.serialize_option(
            {
                if let Some(flags) = &flags {
                    let transaction_flags: Vec<u32> = flags.into_iter().map(|&flag| {
                        let f = flag;
                        let n = f.into();
                        n
                    }).collect();
                    transaction_flags.iter().sum::<u32>()
                } else {
                    0
                }
            }
        )
    }

    fn deserialize<'de, D>(d: D) -> Result<D::Ok, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let specified_flags = u32::deserialize(d).unwrap();
        d.deserialize_u32(
    {
                if specified_flags == 0 {
                    None
                } else {
                    todo!()  // convert to `Vec` of `...Flag` enum
                }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

So I can use the module in the `Foo` struct like this:

```rust
#[skip_serializing_none]
#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all(serialize = "PascalCase", deserialize = "snake_case"))]
pub struct Foo<'a> {
  account: &'a str,
  #[serde(with = "flag_conversion")]
  flags: Option<Vec<FooFlag>>
}
```

Comment: What's your question? "I get a wall of compiler errors, how to [fix](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b904ca7ec6a6f011180e9b5627918829)"? Or how to implement converting an u32 into a Vec of flags (I think you need to make your own trait for that.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're quite close to getting this working.

The key is adding the `#[serde(with="some_module")]` attribute to the `flags` field. you need to implement the serialization/deserialization of the `Option<Vec<FooFlag>>` in that module. (And you can remove `Serialize`/`Deserialize` from the `FooFlag` struct.)

I'm not sure exactly how you want your ints to convert to flags, so I've hard coded that section of code. I'd usually be using power of 2 for the flags which you're not doing...

```
use serde::Deserializer;
use serde::Serializer;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize}; // 1.0.147
use serde_json; // 1.0.87

use std::fmt::Display;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all(serialize = "PascalCase", deserialize = "PascalCase"))]
pub struct Foo<'a> {
    account: &'a str,

    #[serde(with = "foo_flag_serde")]
    flags: Option<Vec<FooFlag>>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Eq, PartialEq, Clone, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub enum FooFlag {
    Example1 = 5,
    Example2 = 15,
}

impl FooFlag {
    pub fn from_u32(d: u32) -> Vec<FooFlag> {
        vec![FooFlag::Example1, FooFlag::Example2]
    }

    pub fn to_u32(v: &[FooFlag]) -> u32 {
        123
    }
}

pub mod foo_flag_serde {
    use super::*;

    pub fn serialize<S>(flags: &Option<Vec<FooFlag>>, serializer: S) -> Result<S::Ok, S::Error>
    where
        S: Serializer,
    {
        let v: Option<u32> = flags.as_ref().map(|f| FooFlag::to_u32(&f));
        v.serialize(serializer)
    }

    pub fn deserialize<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Option<Vec<FooFlag>>, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let v: Option<u32> = Option::deserialize(deserializer)?;
        Ok(v.map(FooFlag::from_u32))
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let data = r#"{"Account": "some_account","Flags": 20}"#;

    let deserialized: Foo = serde_json::from_str(&data).unwrap();

    println!("deserialized = {:?}", deserialized);

    let serialized = serde_json::to_string(&deserialized).unwrap();

    println!("serialized = {:?}", serialized);
}
```

Working on the [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8d8c1d883c99d8c1ed8a0b45b3c0f234)

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Is there a way that ˋdeserializeˋ  returns a generic value so I can use the module for other structures that have other flags? Or would I need to create an own module for each structure I have?

Comment: You can make it a little more general by introducing a `Flag` trait, then making serialize/deserialize work off those, see https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ad1a46f54a5f9281282ebd96d4b9f71b . You could switch away from using`u32` by adding a type to the `Flag` trait, but it would make the serialize/deserialize pair  more complicated. (Probably easier to just create Flag32 and Flag64 etc for types with different flag length requirements)

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot move away from using u32 because it's extern data I'm receiving. The solution you suggested seems really nice. Thank you 